# Creating a WMI filter covering two classes

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy, wmi

I'm trying to create a WMI filter to select all workstations and RDS servers

I currently am using

`SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE (ProductType = "1") OR (CSName = "288-RDS01") OR (CSName = "288-RDS02")`

But if the RDS server names change this will not work.

Ideally I would like to run something closer to

`SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE (ProductType = "1"); 
SELECT * FROM Win32_ServerFeature WHERE ID = 18`

From my research it seems like if I have 2 queries applied to the filter, both would have to return true for the filter to return true.

Is this possible or is the first query the best I am going to get?

I ended up going with

`SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE (ProductType = "1") OR (CSName LIKE "288-RDS%")`

But if anyone has improvements or another way of doing it I would like to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have a naming convention, so maybe you can do something like this:
`SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE (Name LIKE '%-RDS%') OR (Name LIKE '%whatever%')`

Comment: We have a naming convention for Servers, so I will need to keep using ProductType and CSName but that will work. I was trying to keep it as flexible as possible but I can see another way to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following WMI query should work - under Win32_OperatingSystem there's a OSProductSuite value that you can use to detect Terminal Services, which is the old name for a Remote Desktop Server.

I can't find a way to do bitwise operations in WQL, so based on your environment, you may need Terminal Services (16), or Terminal Services running on Windows Server Enterprise Edition (16+2 = 18), or Terminal Services running on Windows Server Datacenter Edition (128+2 = 144), and possibly other combinations - but it does work.

The final ProductType = 1 covers workstations.

```
SELECT OSProductSuite, ProductType FROM Win32_OperatingSystem WHERE OSProductSuite = "16" OR OSProductSuite = "18" OR OSProductSuite = "144" OR ProductType = "1"
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem